# Know vs knew, are these forms ungrammatical?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-perfect

My brother sent me a video showing a Hollywood actor's stupid Tiktok videos. I responded to it with

> *Willis has been an idiotic oldie since several years ago, I **knew** this. But, I **didnt know** he has been so awful a retard*

Are the forms in bold type ungrammatical?

I have searched for a satisfying answer here and there, but I could not find it despite the many answers on this matter.

Comment: There are other problems than the words in bold such as "...*has been* ...*since several years ago*" is ungrammatical.

Comment: *"I didn't know that he has been to Madrid"* would be equally wrong

Comment: "Willis has been an idiotic oldie for a few years now. I knew this. But, I didn't know he is/was so awful a retard". Plus, why so mean?

Comment: @Mari but this structure is quite common in informal/practical English. I have seen *knew* is followed by the present or the present perfect many times

Comment: Did I mention anything about *knew* in the comments?

Comment: @cocovin what is wrong with *since several years ago*? Doesn't it bear the same sense as that of *for several years*?

Comment: Please look up present perfect tense with regards to "duration" of time. **We have lived in Seoul FOR  several years.** and **We have lived in Seoul SINCE  2005**

Comment: @mari you didn't, but you suggest *has* be replaced with *had* because I used *knew*, not *know*, right?

Comment: If you're intetested in improving your level of English, this is the right site for you. If you want to insist that the other constructions are acceptable in informal English, which they're not because the majority of  native speakers don't speak like that, then you're in the wrong place.

Comment: @mari I see. Sorry for insisting. Thanks a bunch for the great answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me, knew and know have been used in a fairly appropriate sense here. However, I think that the grammatical issues here arise not because of the use of knew/know, but rather the framing of the rest of the sentence. It probably should've been framed as:
" I knew that Willis was an idiotic oldie for years, but I didn't know he was such a retard. "

Comment: Using the past in those clauses did cross my mind, but since such precision in grammar is often ignored in practical English by natives, I decided to do likewise. Don't you think it is often ignored?

Comment: Actually, I don't and I think that's why we are a part of this forum - to 'not' ignore the grammatical accuracy of a statement.

Answer (score 1):

The only ungrammatical thing I notice is that the "didn't" should have an apostrophe as shown here. Or you could use "did not" instead. Otherwise grammatically fine.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hahaha. Of course. Sorry for not changing it. It is a whatsapp message, so it is that informal. Thanks a lot. It does answer it, but I am still looking forward to others' replies :)

Comment: Okay great. While other replies are fine, it discourages me that my reply was worthy of a downvote! I am new to this site. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Downvoted because you claim the only ungrammatical aspect is the missing apostrophe.  There are multiple problems and for the OP to comment beneath mae's answer that precision is often ignored in English grammar but at the same time ask whether the words in bold are grammatical, is perplexing, to say the least.

Comment: No one downvoted yours, Ajay.

Comment: @FadliSheikh I downvoted, check Ajay's activity/reputation page. Currently there are 2 upvotes and 1 downvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA sorry for that.